# Cannot access QMainWindow variables from child class

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault, parent, global

I'm trying to set a variable that can be accessed from multiple children at the MainWindow (QMainWindow) level. The issue is whenever I try to access it from a child (or grandchild), I get a segmentation fault.

Here's a mock up of the involved code:

```
//MainWindow.h
...
public:
    int getVariable();
    void setVariable(int i);
...
private:
    int globalInt;
    SomeWidget *myWidget;


//MainWindow.cpp
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ...
    this->globalInt = 10;
    myWidget = new SomeWidget();
    myWidget->setParent(this);
    ....
}
int getVariable()
{
    return this->globalInt;
}
void setVariable(int i)
{
    this->globalInt = i;
}
...



//SomeWidget.cpp
...
int x = (static_cast<MainWindow*>(this->parent()))->getVariable(); //Causes Segfault
...
```

I honestly have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I've tried creating a new MainWindow* pointer to the parent and casting it, I've tried making the "global" int public and directly accessing it, etc. etc. Any ideas what I need to do?

Comment: Try to use [qobject_cast](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#qobject_cast), and try `qDebug() << this->parent()`. That will help to figure out what had happened.

Comment: Where in the code is that last line from? It would crash in the actor, as parent isn't set it. I'd advise to ever access your parent like that and instead have the parent widget pass the value to the child instead.

Comment: That last line is further down in the code. I did make sure the parent is set - new SomeWidget(this).

Comment: Additionally, the issue here about passing from parent to child is that I have a dock parented to the QMainWindow, and separate "project" children. I need the children to be able to see the current state of a variable stored in the parent. The other way would be to update every single child to the current state of a variable, but I only want to do that as a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `reinterpret_cast`. Note that this is not a secure way, because you can make pointers *"that point to an object of an incompatible class, and thus dereferencing it is unsafe."* ([Info](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/))

I just arrived at work so I only had time for a little (and ugly) example, a small console program.

```
class some_widget
{
public:
    some_widget(){ m_parent = 0;}

    void set_parent( void* p_parent ){m_parent= p_parent;}
    void* get_parent(){return m_parent;}

    void do_something();

private:
    void* m_parent;
};

class main_window
{
public:
    main_window(void);
    ~main_window(void){ delete myWidget; myWidget = 0;}

    int getVariable(){return global_int;}
    void setVariable(int i){global_int = i;}

    some_widget* get_widget(){return myWidget;}

private:
    int global_int;
    some_widget *myWidget;
};

main_window::main_window(void)
{
    global_int = 10;
    myWidget = new some_widget();
    myWidget->set_parent(this);
}

void some_widget::do_something()
{
    if( this->get_parent() != 0 )
    {
        int x = reinterpret_cast<main_window*>(this->get_parent())->getVariable();
    }
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    main_window* mw = new main_window();

    mw->get_widget()->do_something();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Apparently I cannot code when I'm tired. I was two parents off from actually being at the MainWindow, duh.. reinterpret_cast<MainWindow*>(this->parent()->parent()->parent()->parent()->variable) did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Simply pass *this to `SomeWidget` as a constructor parameter:

```
myWidget = new SomeWidget(this);
```

And than later in implementation of the `SomeWidget` you can access members of MainWindow following way:

```
void SomeWidget::someFunc() {
    MainWindow *w = qobject_cast<MainWindow*>(parent());
    //cphecing the pointer
    if(w != 0) {
         //accessing MainWindow functionality
         int myInt = w->globalInt;
    }
```

Comment: I've tried this as well, using qpbject_cast instead of dynamic_cast (also static_cast), but the segfault still occurs when I try to retrieve the globalInt.